# i have a view containing a text view and i want to hide it initially and when clicked on the check bool it appears

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am having a view containing a text view named sentence and there is image placed on it and i want to hide it initially when i click on the check bool the text view apears and the again clicked it will disappear.

Here is my code-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    checkBool = false;
    [textView setHidden:!checkBool];


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    [checkBox setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unselected.png"]
                        forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [checkBox setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"]
                        forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [textView setDelegate:self];
    textView.text =false;
    IsHidden = true;
    [textView setHidden:IsHidden];

    if (IsHidden) {
        IsHidden = false;
    }else
        IsHidden = true;
    [textView setHidden:IsHidden];
    if (IsHidden) {
        IsHidden = false;
    }else
        IsHidden = true;    


}
-(IBAction)checkBox:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"button press");
    checkBool = !checkBool;
    [checkBox setSelected:checkBool];
    [textView setHidden:!checkBool];

    if (checkBool) {

        [textView becomeFirstResponder];
    }else{
        [textView resignFirstResponder];

    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try these i hope it helps..

```
-(IBAction)checkBox:(id)sender
{
    if (!checkBox.selected)
    {
        checkBox.selected=YES;
        [textView setHidden:NO];
    }
    else
    {
        checkBox.selected=NO;
        [textView setHidden:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)checkBox:(UIButton *)sender{
            NSLog(@"button press");
          sender.selected=!sender.selected;
            if ([sender isSelected]==YES)
                [textView setHidden:NO];
            else
                [textView setHidden:YES];
    }
```

and just set in view Didload method, **textview setHidden=YES;**

Answer (score 0):

Create property for text view

```
@property(weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *someImage;
```

and show the IBOutlet as per requirement

```
-(IBAction)checkBox:(id)sender
{
    if(!checkBox.selected)
    {
      checkBox.selected=YES;
      self.someImage.hidden = Yes;
    }
    else
    {
      checkBox.selected=NO;
      self.someImage.hidden = No;
    }
}
```